# Constant Reference Wrapper

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, constants

I came across the following piece of code in the book on data structures by Mark Allen Weiss.

```
template <class Object>
class Cref
{
public:
Cref ( ) : obj ( NULL ) { }
explicit Cref( const Object & x ) : obj ( &x ) {
const Object & get( ) const
{
if ( isNull( ) )
  throw NullPointerException( ) ;
else
 return *obj;
}
bool isNull( ) const
( return obj == NULL; }

private:
const Object *obj;
};
```

So the point here is to assign null/initialize a constant reference. But I am not sure I understand the following: 
1. We initialize a constant reference with another constant reference x. But why is it again done as obj(&x) ? the & in const Object & x is different from the &x in obj(&x) ? I see this but not very clear why it should be so. Pls explain. 
2. The get method() - We try to return a const reference of the private member obj of this class. It is already a const reference. Why return *obj  and not just obj ? 
3. Why explicit keyword ? What might happen if an implicit type conversion takes place ? Can someone provide a scenario for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The member `obj` is of type `Object*`, but the constructor takes a reference. Therefore to get a pointer, the address-of operator, `&`, has to be applied. And the member is a pointer because it can be NULL (set in the default constructor), and references never can be NULL.
2. The private member is *not* a const reference, but a *poinetr* to const. It is dereferenced to get a reference.
3. In this specific case, I cannot see any negative effect of a potential implicit conversion either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! Especially #2! :)

Comment: Also about #1, this means that this is a matter with the declaration. Since we can only declare a const reference like const Object & x; when actually assigning it to a pointer, it is inevitable that ptr = &x is done. Is my reason correct ?

Comment: @SuprajaJayakumar: From a logical point of view, a reference basically names an object. That is, inside the constructor the object passed to it has the name `x` (and is const because it is a const reference). Therefore you use `x` exactly as you'd use a variable of that type. To get a pointer to a variable, you use the addess-of operator, `&`, and therefore you do the same with `x`. The fact that a reference is also defined using the symbol `&` is logically unrelated to this. It would have been the same if they had decided to use a keyword `ref` for that.

Answer (score 1):

1) `&x` in `obj(&x)` is used as the address-of operator.

2) No, it is a pointer. Its time is `Object *`, not `Object &`.

3) To prevent casting from incompatible pointer types which might have their own type-cast operator.

C++ has three flavors of null available:

- `NULL` - obsolete; use it only for checking the return values of C functions which return pointers
- `0`  - deprecated; the literal zero is defined in the Standard to be the null pointer
- `nullptr` - as of C++11, this is the preferred way of testing for null. Furthermore, `nullptr_t` is a type-safe null.

Answer (score 0):

1) The token `&` has three meanings:

- Unary address-of operator: Take the address of any lvalue expression, giving a pointer to that object.
- Reference sigil: In a declaration, means a reference type.
- Binary bitwise AND operator - not used here

So it's important to know whether you're looking at a declaration or an expression.

```
explicit Cref( const Object & x )
```

Here the sigil appears in the declaration of a function parameter, meaning the type of parameter `x` is a reference to an `Object` which is `const`.

```
: obj ( &x ) {}
```

Here the operator is used in a member initializer expression.  Member `obj` is initialized to be a pointer to `x`.

2) Since member `obj` is actually a pointer, the dereference operator unary `*` is needed to get a reference.

3) In general, it's a good idea to use `explicit` on any (non-copy) constructor which can take exactly one argument.  It's just unfortunate that the language doesn't default to explicit and make you use some sort of "implicit" keyword instead when you mean to.  In this case, here's one rather bad thing that could happen if the constructor were implicit:

```
Object create_obj();
void setup_ref(Cref& ref) {
    ref = create_obj();
}
```

No compiler error or warning, but that `setup_ref` function stores a pointer to a temporary object, which is invalid by the time the function returns!

Answer (score 0):

1)  The type of obj is not a reference, obj is a pointer,  and a const pointer must be initialized with a address, so, the address-of operator, &, must be applied.
2) The reference the get() method returns is not a reference to the class member obj, but a reference to the object which obj points, so you have to use * to deference it.
3) The keyword explicit means we reject the implicit conversions, that is, we tell the compiler, don't make implicit conversions with this constructor for us.
Example:

`class Cref<Object> A;

Object B;

A=B;`

It's OK without the explicit--Since we need a Cref object on the right side, the compiler will automate making a Cref object with constructor Cref( const Object & B ). But if you add an explicit, the compiler won't make conversions, there will be a compiling error.